# ESP32 Consequtive Interrupt WDT Timeout Exception

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp32, arduino-esp32, platformio

I am working on an IoT application with over 15K lines of code using PlatformIO IDE, Espressif 6.2.0, and the Arduino framework for the ESP32 WROOM target.

I left the device running for about 28 hours, and everything was working fine until I encountered the following exception, which simply stated that the ISR WDT (Interrupt Service Routine Watchdog Timer) had timed out, which is understandable.

However, what happened next really confused me. The device attempted to reboot **97** times, and each attempt resulted in the same error. On the 98th attempt, the device got stuck in the reboot process and did not proceed further. It seemed as if the CPU was halted, but I do not know why or how exactly.

I have a single ISR in my program attached to a digital input. In that ISR, I only increment an integer variable by one and nothing else.

My question is, why might this have happened? Let's consider that my program has a major problem that occurs after 28 hours, but why doesn't the issue stop after rebooting?

Has anyone had a similar experience, and if so, what were the possible solutions?

Here is the start and end of the log for your reference:

```
[T-97929] [N] Free Heap Size: 55464, Min Heap Size: 16372
[97929352][E][Wire.cpp:513] requestFrom(): i2cRead returned Error 263
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40081467  PS      : 0x00050a35  A0      : 0x4008522c  A1      : 0x3ffbfaac  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3ffbe12c  A4      : 0x3ffbe14c  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x3ffbe14c  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x00000001  A9      : 0x3ffbfa8c  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x00000001  
A14     : 0x00000001  A15     : 0x3ffb8ff0  SAR     : 0x0000001b  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008a468  LEND    : 0x4008a47e  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400f6137  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x40081464:0x3ffbfaac |<-CORRUPTED


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4018d46a  PS      : 0x00060735  A0      : 0x800f4bcc  A1      : 0x3ffcc580  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x80000001  A4      : 0x800921f8  A5      : 0x3ffaf660  
A6      : 0x00000003  A7      : 0x00060023  A8      : 0x800f46ae  A9      : 0x3ffcc550  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x80000001  A12     : 0x800921f8  A13     : 0x3ffaf670  
A14     : 0x00000003  A15     : 0x00060023  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4018d467:0x3ffcc580 0x400f4bc9:0x3ffcc5a0 0x400902c4:0x3ffcc5c0




ELF file SHA256: ed76320984d99ab6

Rebooting...
[T-0] [N] Setup Started.
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008520c  PS      : 0x00050035  A0      : 0x4000bff0  A1      : 0x3ffbfadc  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000040  A4      : 0x00001000  A5      : 0x3ffbfaac  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x3ffbe12c  A8      : 0x0002566a  A9      : 0x3ffbfaac  
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x00000804  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x3ffbfa8c  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001b  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008a5d0  LEND    : 0x4008a5db  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400f6137  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x40085209:0x3ffbfadc |<-CORRUPTED


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4018d46a  PS      : 0x00060735  A0      : 0x800f4bcc  A1      : 0x3ffcc580  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x4008981c  A4      : 0x00060520  A5      : 0x3ffbcfb0  
A6      : 0x007bfaf8  A7      : 0x003fffff  A8      : 0x800f46ae  A9      : 0x3ffcc550  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x3ffbfaf4  A12     : 0x3ffbfaf4  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00060520  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4018d467:0x3ffcc580 0x400f4bc9:0x3ffcc5a0 0x400902c4:0x3ffcc5c0




ELF file SHA256: ed76320984d99ab6

.
.
.
. 97 Exception Like This
.
.
.
.

Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40085204  PS      : 0x00050a35  A0      : 0x4008182e  A1      : 0x3ffbfadc  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3ffb78e0  A4      : 0x00001000  A5      : 0x3ffbfaac  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x3ffbe12c  A8      : 0x3ffbe168  A9      : 0x00000000  
A10     : 0x3ffbe14c  A11     : 0x00000001  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x3ffbfa8c  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001b  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008a468  LEND    : 0x4008a47e  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400f6137  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x40085201:0x3ffbfadc |<-CORRUPTED


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4018d46a  PS      : 0x00060935  A0      : 0x800f4bcc  A1      : 0x3ffcc580  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x80000001  A4      : 0x800921f8  A5      : 0x3ffcc4a0  
A6      : 0x00000003  A7      : 0x00060023  A8      : 0x800f46ae  A9      : 0x3ffcc550  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x80000001  A12     : 0x800921f8  A13     : 0x3ffaf630  
A14     : 0x00000003  A15     : 0x00060023  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4018d467:0x3ffcc580 0x400f4bc9:0x3ffcc5a0 0x400902c4:0x3ffcc5c0




ELF file SHA256: ed76320984d99ab6

Rebooting...
[T-0] [N] Setup Started.
```